# Issue setting frame for UIImageView before applying constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm coming across an issue with the following lines of code:

```
 let imageName = "smiley.png"
 let imageU = UIImage(named: imageName)
 let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageU)
 imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
 contentView!.addSubview(imageView)
 let imageTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy:  NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bodyText, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
 let imageLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, relatedBy:  NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)
 imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([imageTopConstraint, imageLeftConstraint])
```

When I run this code, I am getting a gigantic smiley (probably 150x150) and the constraints don't seem to be working correctly either. Is there something wrong with setting the frame and then applying constraints? What is the best practice when creating and constraining views programmatically? Thanks, and apologies for the semi-vague question.

Comment: If your image is static, why don't you add with storyboard and put constraints there itself. If you are setting the frame yourself then don't add layout constraints

Comment: This image may or may not be added to the view depending on what data comes back from a web server.

Comment: lock height and width of image view or just remove constraints

Comment: The issue here is that you constrain only the position of the image but not its size and so the image just uses its natural size. You can either add constraints for the size by supplying top/bottom constraints or by directly setting width/height constants. Setting the frame _and_ using constraints is contradictory. Finally, you could indeed set the icon at your storyboard/xib and show/hide it based on some condition.